# Controlling view visibility from a resources

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view, android-resources

I have a layout that contains two ImageViews. I want one of them to be visible in portrait and the other in landscape. How do I achieve it using resources? (I know how to set it programmatically for but this specific use I need to achieve it using resources).

I tried something like

in res/layout/may_layout.xml:

```
...
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image1"
      android:visibility="@integer/visible_in_portrait"   <<-- is this allowed?
      ...
/>
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image2"
      android:visibility="@integer/visible_in_landscape"   
      ...
/>
```

in res/values/integers.xml:

```
...
<!-- NOTE: 0 and 8 are VISIBLE and GONE respectively -->
<integer name="visibile_in_portrait">0</integer>
<integer name="visibile_in_landscape">8</integer>
```

in res/values-land/integers.xml:

```
...
<integer name="visibile_in_portrait">8</integer>
<integer name="visibile_in_landscape">0</integer>
```

But I get a runtime error (index out of bound) when trying to inflate the images. When I remove the android:visibility statements, the program runs but I see both images.

Q: What is the way to use a resource as a value for the android:visibility attribute?

(if you wonder why setting it programmatically will not help me, it has to do with automatic landspace/portrait switch of app widgets with file uri bitmaps).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

it will be possible when you use this trick, add your visibility line to a style and put two instances of that file in -land and normal mode.

I mean in file `styles.xml` in folder `values` put a style with name `s1`, and put `android:visibility=visible` in that, and in `styles.xml` in folder `values-land` put a style with name `s1`, and put `android:visibility=gone`.

also, in file `styles.xml` in folder `values` put a style with name `s2`, and put `android:visibility=gone` in that, and in `styles.xml` in folder `values-land` put a style with name `s2`, and put `android:visibility=visible`.

and then, set `s1` to first imageview and `s2` to second.

solution given by dear Calvin is also correct, but when you have a complex layout that may change during time, having one layout file would be better, and will have less need to change.

Comment: Thanks Keyhan, I will give it a try and report here. Will this approach also help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745227/setting-programmatically-the-pixel-size-of-a-remote-imageview . I have 5 different sizes times two modes (portrait and langscape). Use the style also to control the ImageView size?  This way I will have a single layout with two images and 5 pairs of orientation/portrait styles.  (working around the limitations of RemoteViews is not fun ;-)).

Comment: Works well. This was a great help!. Thanks Keyhan.

Comment: The suggested solution involves the usage of [Style Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html)

Comment: Creating a whole style just to set an attribute is not a good practice, especially if you need to set more attributes in styles already (you can't have two styles on a view). [Flávio's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14358801/253468) is much cleaner.

Answer (score 66):

This is an old question that has already been accepted, but the following solution may help someone else:

If you check res/values/attrs.xml in Android source code, you'll see the definition of visibility property like this:

```
 <!-- Controls the initial visibility of the view.  -->
    <attr name="visibility">
        <!-- Visible on screen; the default value. -->
        <enum name="visible" value="0" />
        <!-- Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it). -->
        <enum name="invisible" value="1" />
        <!-- Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added. -->
        <enum name="gone" value="2" />
    </attr>
```

This attribute expects a string value (visible, invisible, gone) that will be converted to (0, 1, 2) respectively. So, you can declare integer resources containing these values like this:

values/integers.xml

```
<integer name="visible_in_portrait">2</integer> <!-- This is GONE -->
```

values-land/integers.xml

```
<integer name="visible_in_landscape">0</integer> <!-- This is VISIBLE -->
```

However, if you want to make it even better in order to stop guessing these numeric constants every time, you could do like this:

values/integers.xml

```
<!-- These are alias for the constants we'll reference below -->
<integer name="view_visible">0</integer> <!-- This is VISIBLE -->
<integer name="view_invisible">1</integer> <!-- This is INVISIBLE -->
<integer name="view_gone">2</integer> <!-- This is GONE -->

<integer name="visible_in_portrait">@integer/view_gone</integer> <!-- We're referencing the visibility alias we declared above -->
```

values-land/integers.xml

```
<integer name="visible_in_landscape">@integer/view_visible</integer>
```

You can use this approach or the one suggested by Keyhan. Choose the one that fits you better.

Comment: It also works declaring them as `<integer>` rather than `<string>`

Comment: the good practice would be to keep the original android values for visible, invisible and gone (not 0, 1, 2, but 0, 4, 8)

Comment: Well, that's not exaclty how it works. If you check the `View` class code, these values (0, 1 and 2) are used to access the positions of this member: `private static final int[] VISIBILITY_FLAGS = {VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, GONE};`. That's why you can't use 0, 4 and 8, because 0, 1 and 2 stand for VISIBLE, INVISIBLE and GONE indices.

Comment: Aliases doesn't work for me (i.e. `view_visible`). It only works if I assign 0, 1, 2 to an integer resource that I use directly. (but +1 for that bit!!)

Comment: From `android.view.View#VISIBLE``android.view.View#INVISIBLE` and `android.view.View#GONE` values of variables should be `<enum name="visible" value="0" /> <enum name="invisible" value="4" /> <enum name="gone" value="8" />`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. (I tried define fill_parent as string and use it for layout_width and it fails too.)

Why don't you use 2 layouts?

1. res/layout/may_layout.xml
2. res/layout-land/may_layout.xml

Which each define the correct imageview to show.

In addition, having values-land may cause you problem when you needs to support multi-languages. (You will need to have value-xx-land for each language)

Comment: Thanks Calvin. I was trying to avoid duplicating the layout, unless I can generate them automatically from a template at build time. Don't know if eclipse supports it and how standard it will be.