# Value xml file holding enum values

Tags: android

I have a text view in a library that, depending on the project, I want to set to visible or invisible. I tried to set a value in a xml value file

```
<string name="vis_text">invisible</string>
```

and then set it in the layout file

```
<TextView ...
  android:visibility="@+id/vis_text"
.../>
```

It didn't work as vis_text is a String while visibility expects an enum. The error said it all:

```
Error: String types not allowed (at 'visibility' with value '`@+id/vis_text')
```

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Don't tell me to do it using code, I will if I cannot do it via xml file :)

Comment: What about you define two versions of your TextView, and use the one you want depending on your needs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751881/controlling-view-visibility-from-a-resources